# Bash: Safe to remove all occurrences of -n inside brackets?

Tags: bash, shell, boolean, is-empty, truthiness

I recently found this "bug" in my bash script;

```
if [ "$var" ]; then
    echo "Condition is true"
fi
```

where what I meant was to check if `$var` is non-empty, i.e. `[ -n "$var" ]`. As it happens, the code seems to work perfectly fine without the `-n`. Similarly, I find that I can replace `[ -z "$var" ]` with `[ ! "$var" ]`.

I tend to like this implicit falseyness (truthiness) based on the (non-)emptyness of a variable in other languages, and so I might adopt this pattern in bash as well. Are there any danger to doing so, i.e. edge cases where the two set of syntaxes are inequivalent?

Comment: As long as you quote the variable it should be fine. But that said, if you are targetting scripts for only `bash`, you should consider using `[[`

Comment: Looking at `man bash`, testing `string` or `-n string` are equivalent. (as long as you quote it as @Inian notes above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we substitute:

```
-n "$var"   ->    "$var" 
-z "$var"   ->    ! "$var"
```

That looks ok and some people do that. There are corner cases where the removal will be harmful and result in syntax errors. These corner cases specially include times, where `var` is equal to a valid `test` argument. Ex. `var=-n` or `var="!"` etc.

Ex:

```
$ v1="-n" v2=""; [ -n "$v1" -o -z "$v2" ]; echo $?
0
```

but

```
$ v1="-n" v2=""; [ "$v1" -o ! "$v2" ]; echo $?
bash: [: too many arguments
2
```

That said, I couldn't find a way on my system (bash 5.0.0) to break it without using `-o` and `-a`. And anyway, the test man page advises to use `&&` and `||` instead of `-a` and `-o`.

But in [POSIX specification test](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) we can find the following application note:

> The two commands:
>
> test "$1"
>   test ! "$1"
>
> could not be used reliably on some historical systems. Unexpected
>   results would occur if such a string expression were used and $1
>   expanded to '!', '(', or a known unary primary. Better constructs are:
>
> test -n "$1"
>   test -z "$1"

So I think as long as you don't use "some historical systems", you are safe. But is it worth the risk? You have to answer yourself.

That said, subjective: I value maintainability and readability much more then saving to type 3 characters and find `-n` and `-z` more readable. The intent with `-n` is clear - test if the string has `-n`onzero length. The intent with `-z` is also clear - test if the string has `-z`ero length. I find it confusing to others to write `[ "$var" ]` and `[ ! "$var" ]`. At first it would look like `$var` has some special meaning inside the `[` `]`.

> I recently found this "bug" in my bash script

It's not a bug, it's a feature!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you make use of single brackets. This implies that you are using the `test` command and not the Bash-builtin function. From the manual :

> **`test EXPRESSION`** or **`[ EXPRESSION ]`:** this exits with the status returned by `EXPRESSION`
>
> **`-n STRING`:**  the length of `STRING` is nonzero.
>
> **`STRING`:**   equivalent to `-n STRING`
>
> **<sub>source: `man test`</sub>**

This should answer your question.

Furthermore:

> **`! EXPRESSION`:**   `test` returns **true** of `EXPRESSION` is **false**
>
> **`-z STRING`:** `test` returns **true** if the length of `STRING` is zero.

Which implies that `[ ! STRING ]` is equivalent to `[ -z STRING ]`.